# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 29: parser error

Tags: view, magento2.3.5-p1, simplexml

May I have Help please

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 29: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php on line 552

Comment: can you post your code where you are getting this error.

Comment: It looks like you are having an error in your layout xml.

Comment: {
        return simplexml_load_string($xmlString, \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element::class);
    }

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 29: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php on line 552

Comment: I haven't made any updates.
I only added a category and that gave me this error.